# When does the equality hold for norm equivalence

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

We know that for a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, its 1-norm and 2-norm satisfy that
$$\frac{1}{n}\|x\|_1\le\|x\|_2\le \|x\|_1,$$
could anyone please give me some hints that on what condition these equality holds?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
If you are given a proof for those estimates, look at them.
The proofs contain some other inequalities that you may be more familiar with.
When does equality hold in them?

A different kind of hint:
What special kind of vectors can you come up with in $\mathbb R^n$?
What are some simple nonzero vectors?

---

The first inequality is not optimal and thus never reached.
If you can show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\|x\|_1\le\|x\|_2$, you can conclude that equality only holds for $x=0$ (or when $n=1$).
To prove this, find a vector $y$ so that $x\cdot y=\|x\|_1$ and use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Are you talking about vectors like $x=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$? They do yield $\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1$, but do not hold $\frac{1}{n}\|x\|_1=\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1$.

Comment: The other kind of vector I had in mind is $x=(1,\dots,1)$. It gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||x||_1=||x||_2$. This is the best you can get. If you are familiar with Lagrange multipliers, they can help in proving that. But I urge you to follow my first hint: look at the proofs. That's often the easiest way.

Comment: @cjferes: Or you can use Cauchy-Scwarz for any $x$ and $y=(\pm1,\pm1,\dots,\pm1)$ with suitably chosen signs. That gives an easier solution for the first inequality.

Comment: I see. But the condition says $\frac{1}{n}\|x\|_1\leq\|x\|_2$. It doesn't have the square root of $n$. But, all in all, the hint to look at the proofs is OK.

Comment: I saw your edit and upvoted the answer. That's a good explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The null vector $x=\vec{0}_n$ yields the equality of norms.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The only situation that gives the equality for real vectors is $\vec{0}$.

Comment: I suppose that people do not appreciate much "trivial" answers. When discussing sharpness of norm equivalence constants, one is rather interested in *nonzero* vectors for which the lower and upper bounds are attained (generally different vectors). The zero vector is utterly uninteresting since it does not say anything about the sharpness of the bounds.

Comment: That is right, but the answer of the OP is the **only** solution. Well, s**t happens ;)

Comment: I believe that the grammar used in many questions does not really express what one wants to know the answer for. In particular, when the question is not correctly formulated as, e.g., here :)

Comment: i'll take note of your comment/answer to give better answers in the future. Thanks @AlgebraicPavel